# Kernel32 CopyFile does not find a file which exists c#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I invoked Kernel32's copy file method like that:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
           SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CopyFile(
                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpExistingFileName,
                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpNewFileName,
                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bFailIfExists);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetLastError();
```

However when I call it it return 2 from the GetLastError() which means file not found.
The path certainly exists.

```
string newfile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp" + Path.GetExtension(file);
uint i;
if (!CopyFile(file, newfile, true)) i = GetLastError();
```

I'm trying to bypass the LongPath exception with this solution. But it doesn't seem to work even with normal files. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the complete code of Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Shell32;
using System.Xml;
using System.Diagnostics;
using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DocumentCrawler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll",
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
           SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CopyFile(
                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpExistingFileName,
                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpNewFileName,
                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bFailIfExists);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetLastError();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            lbProgress.Text = "Finding Word Documents";
            btnSearch.Enabled = false;
            lvResults.Clear();
            SearchDirectory(tbDirectory.Text, tbField.Text);
            btnSearch.Enabled = true;
        }

        void SearchDirectory(string path, string searchPattern)
        {
            List<string> docs = new List<string>();
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                SearchDirectory(path + "\\" + d.Remove(0, d.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1), searchPattern);
            }

            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(f) == ".docx" || Path.GetExtension(f) == ".doc")
                {
                    docs.Add(f);
                }
            }

            progressBar.Value = 0;
            lbProgress.Text = "Processing Word Documents 0%";
            progressBar.Maximum = docs.Count;
            progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;

            foreach (string f in docs)
            {
                string txt = TextFromDocument(f);
                if (txt.Contains(searchPattern))
                {
                    lvResults.Items.Add(f);
                }
                progressBar.Value++;
                lbProgress.Text = "Processing Word Documents " + ((int)((float)progressBar.Value / (float)progressBar.Maximum * 100)) + "%";
            }
        }

        string TextFromDocument(string file)
        {
            string newfile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\temp" + Path.GetExtension(file);
            uint i;
            if (!CopyFile(file, newfile, true)) i = GetLastError();
            object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            word.Application wordApp = new word.Application();
            word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(newfile, false);

            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            string text = doc.Content.Text;

            doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
            wordApp.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

            File.Delete(newfile);

            return text;
        }

        private void lvResults_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(lvResults.SelectedItems[0].Text);
            lvResults.SelectedItems[0].ForeColor = Color.Purple;
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbDirectory.Text = fd.SelectedPath;
                btnSearch.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is not the directory the exe was launched from. Can you post an executable repro?

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about with the repro thing. But Envinronment.CurrentDirectory works in every place for me. I know it can change in one application. But it worked fine for now. It even produces error with "C:\\temp" + Path.GetExtension(file)

Comment: Repro is an executable code snippet meant to reproduce the issue. At the moment I cannot run the code and see for myself.

Comment: I've added the full source code of Form1.

Comment: Rather than us having to create a windows forms app, work out the correct controls, etc, could you try to create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Preferably, it would be a console app that first creates the source file and then attempts to use `CopyFile` to  copy it, rather than something fiddling around with progress bars, etc.

Comment: Your [MarshalAs] attribute on the strings is incompatible with the CharSet you specified.  So the strings are marshaled wrong.  Just remove the attributes.  There is no point in pinvoking CopyFile() yourself, the .NET File.Copy() method already does that.

Comment: @HansPassant I guess he wants to prepend `@"\\?\"` and escape the 260 character filename length limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",
   CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
   CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
   SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CopyFile(
                   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpExistingFileName,
                   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpNewFileName,
                   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bFailIfExists);
```

In the `DllImport` declaration you select the `CharSet.Unicode` character set. This will mean that the p/invoke function will be bound to `CopyFileW`.

But then you subsequently instruct the marshaller to marshal the parameters as `LPStr`, ANSI strings. This is the reason why the function always fails.

A correct p/invoke would be:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CopyFile(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
    bool bFailIfExists);
```

You absolutely should not p/invoke `GetLastError`. Instead use [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) for the reasons described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx).